# How can I get the local filepath from the fileinput using javascript in IE9?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

The application of image-preview  has troubles in IE9,like the picture,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGKDm.jpg]

this method can't work well and throw an error,but in ie6-8,it works well.
I want to get the true filepath from the fileinput ,not the path like "C:\fakepath*.*",my browser is ie9.
Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. This is a security feature that can't be removed.

Comment: And this is good. It's none of your business where a file the user is uploading is located on his system.

Comment: I want to have the function of image-preview.

Comment: @紫竹郎 I understand. However, it's no longer possible. You would need to use a Flash based uploader - but those require Flash of course,  work in a different way from a normal file upload, and I'm not aware of a ready-made product that does image previews